# How to disable a Material UI css class for an element globally

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the Typography element from Material UI. It has a css class MuiTypography-h1. I want it to be disabled across all the places in the codebase i.e. globally.

```html
<Typography
  variant="h1"
  sx={{
      width: '100px',
      height: '55px',
      fontSize: '20px',
      fontWeight: 500,
      lineHeight: '1.2',
      WebkitLineClamp: 4,
      WebkitBoxOrient: 'vertical',
      marginTop: '11px',
  }}
>
  Title
</Typography>
```

Comment: you can create a styled component for typography and then use it across you application in that way you can modularize you code and use the custom typography tag

Answer (score 0):

you can use makeTheme and then generate one style for all typography tags across app:
Take a look in documentation here:
https://mui.com/customization/theming/

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    body1: {
      fontWeight: 500,
      fontSize: 18,
      color: "green"
    }
  }
})

export default theme;
```